# What code can I use to combine mata and matb to get the output shown?

Tags: matrix

[image]

What code can I use to combine mata and matb to get the output shown?

Comment: Please post your actual code rather than a screenshot.  That being said, does `MapThread[List, {mata, matb}, 2]` produce the desired result?

Comment: Also `Transpose /@ Transpose@{mata, matb}`

Answer (score 2):

Using a rule:

```
mata = {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {g, h, i}};
matb = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
mata + matb /. Plus -> List
```

if you want the letters first:

```
Reverse[mata + matb /. Plus -> List, 3]
```

A bit more robust might be:

```
Thread[Join @@@ {mata, matb}]
```

Comment: The first two solutions are of course hacks that only work because the two lists are so distinct.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways. One could be

```
mata = {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {g, h, i}}
matb = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}
```

And now

```
 MapThread[Partition[Riffle[#1, #2], 2] &, {mata, matb}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And please post plain text code so it is easy to copy and use. Mathematica still does not have an AI/neural network function which can read code from images.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the 3-arg form of [`MapThread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapThread):

```
MapThread[List, {mata, matb}, 2]
```

> {{{a, 1}, {b, 2}, {c, 3}}, {{d, 4}, {e, 5}, {f, 6}}, {{g, 7}, {h, 8}, {i, 9}}}